# Enable Membership Captcha on specific forms in ExpressionEngine

Tags: members, solspace-user, captcha

I am working on a website based on ExpressionEngine, which requires captcha on the member registration form.

For this, I enabled Membership captcha, and added the below code in the form.

```
{if captcha}
    <p>Please enter the word you see in the image below:</p>
    <p>{captcha}<br />
    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" /></p>
{/if}
```

It works fine, it shows the captcha as required. But the problem is, the website is divided into 2 parts:

- Free membership registration
- Paid membership registration

And I require captcha only on "Free membership registration" form and not on all the membership registration forms. I tried almost everything, and it has been 2 days, I am stuck with this problem.

Please let me know, how can carry this out? Help on this will be highly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, requiring a captcha is site-wide, not form-specific.

I'd suggest instead looking at [Snaptcha](https://www.putyourlightson.net/snaptcha), which is far more effective and requires no input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Derek Hogue for the reply. But I have found a work-around for this. 
I manipulated the config file according to the URI.Changed the LINE #173, and added an IF-ELSE condition.

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"<Mypage_URI_Where_I_Dont_Cant_Captcha>") || stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"<Mypage_URI_Where_I_Dont_Cant_Captcha>")){
    $config['captcha_require_members'] = 'N';
}else{
    $config['captcha_require_members'] = 'y';
}
```

I hope this helps someone looking for a similar work-around. Many thanks once again.